# Meteor Spiderable Errors

Tags: meteor, phantomjs

My phantomjs/spiderable package keeps failing on production.

```
spiderable: phantomjs failed: Error: Command failed:
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:648:15)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
spiderable: phantomjs failed: Error: Command failed:
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:648:15)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
spiderable: phantomjs failed: Error: Command failed:
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:648:15)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
spiderable: phantomjs failed: Error: Command failed:
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:648:15)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
spiderable: phantomjs failed: Error: Command failed:
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:648:15)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)

/mnt/data/2/programs/server/packages/meteorhacks:kadira.js:2569
    throw err;
          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'stack' of null
    at Object.Meteor._debug (packages/meteorhacks:kadira/lib/hijack/error.js:53)
    at packages/spiderable/spiderable_server.js:101
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:646:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
[2014-09-10T07:44:15.144Z] Application CRASH detected. Exit code 7.
```

If I go to a usual url on the site I don't see the error but if I tail the logs this happens pretty frequently. Any idea on how to debug and figure this out?

Comment: Same with me. Any progress on this?

Comment: ditto here too... obviously this hasn't had any traction though

Comment: Is PhantomJS definitely installed on the production server?

Comment: You can try to install [different forks](https://atmospherejs.com/?q=spide) of spiderable package. We use [`jazeee:spiderable-longer-timeout`](https://atmospherejs.com/jazeee/spiderable-longer-timeout) and it work like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Spiderable is known for being pretty unreliable. I suggest using Prerender instead if you can: http://prerender.io

Answer (score 0):

Spirerable package works only as a wrapper for phantomjs. Read  the notes:

> If you deploy your application with meteor bundle, you must install phantomjs (http://phantomjs.org) somewhere in your $PATH. If you use meteor deploy this is already taken care of.

So, you have to install phantomjs on your server yourself:

```
sudo npm install phantomjs
```

These packages could be helpful:

[dfischer:phantomjs](https://atmospherejs.com/dfischer/phantomjs)

```
meteor add dfischer:phantomjs
```

or
[gadicohen:phantomjs](https://atmospherejs.com/gadicohen/phantomjs)

```
meteor add gadicohen:phantomjs
```